# Mac OSX - How can I enable sharing with windows machines?

Tags: mac, file-sharing

I was looking at this link - http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2003/03/18/samba.html?page=1#at

The link says I should have SMB as an option in the services list in my Directory Utility. But I don't see it there. I am using Mac OSX 10.5.7

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up System Preferences -> Sharing. Check "File Sharing" then click "Options." Check "Share Files and Folders using SMB (Windows)"